# Setup public key authorized SSH for non-root users

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, ssh-keys, public-key

I was able to setup ssh login using public keys for root users and tried to apply the same logic for non-root users. I have tried to troubleshoot this issue in vain. I am using centos for both my local machine and remote server.

Here is a gist of my sshd_config file a my remote server,

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PublicKeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/user/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication no

UsePAM no

PermitRootLogin without-password
```

I have moved my authorized keys file away from the user's home to /etc/ssh/user/authorized_keys as I read about home dir encryption in centos.

I have also changed the ownership of all files/dirs associated to the non-root user.

Not sure what step I am missing in my config as the same config works very well for root remote logins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the authorized_keys entry in your config file.  Restart sshd.  Make a .ssh directory in your non-root user home directory.  Put the key in a file called ~/.ssh/authorized keys.  Make the directory 0700 and the authorized_keys file 0644.  Do the same for the root user.

Comment: Do you want me to use the same authorized_keys file for both root and non-root user?

Comment: Up to you...............

Comment: I am still getting the same permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: When I tried ssh user@remotehost as a root user the authentication failed. But when I tried logging in as "user" the connection went through. This is a start, thanks  a lot!

Comment: The root ssh key file goes in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Restarting SSH was the kicker for me.  I guess it doesn't read the file permissions except when it initializes.  I also made sure to `chown` the files to the user whose home directory I was in. Don't accidentally leave root as the owner of the files.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, you need the PUBLIC key file (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) from the origin machine to be in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the destination machine.

If you copy over ~/.ssh/id_rsa then that won't work.  Modern sshd will also insist on ~/.ssh being mode 700 and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys being mode 600 on the destination machine.

Aside: if you can, use sudo instead of allowing root logins over ssh.

Comment: Actually 644 is OK for authorized_keys. When all is said and done it is a list of public keys.